# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /ratinglist.jsp at line 50

Tags: mysql, jsp

Ok I have tried working on this for an hour and I am sure it's easy but I think I am blind to my own code. This page should just retrieve data sent to an Arraylist retrieved by a query to mysql. Here is the Tomcat Log:

```
    06-Mar-2016 20:42:26.465 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [RatingServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /ratinglist.jsp at line 50

47:                 <tr>
48:                     <td>${newrating.scale}</td>
49:                     <td>${newrating.userid}</td>
50:                     <td>${newrating.text_rating}</td>
51:                     <td></td>
52:                     <%--  <td>${newrating.text_rating}</td> --%>
53:                     <td></td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'text_rating' not found on type edu.csueb.cs6665.bean.Ratings
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:245)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:222)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:956)
    at org.apache.jsp.ratinglist_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(ratinglist_jsp.java:173)
    at org.apache.jsp.ratinglist_jsp._jspService(ratinglist_jsp.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at edu.csueb.cs6665.servlet.RatingServlet.processRequest(RatingServlet.java:127)
    at edu.csueb.cs6665.servlet.RatingServlet.doGet(RatingServlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is what I have:

ratinglist.jsp

```
 <body>
    <jsp:include page="/include/header.jsp"/>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Videos List</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Scale</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Video</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="newrating" items="${newrating}">
            <tr>
                <td>${newrating.scale}</td>
                <td>${newrating.userid}</td>
                <td>${newrating.text_rating}</td>
                <td></td>
                <%--  <td>${newrating.text_rating}</td> --%>
                <td></td>
                <%-- <td>${newrating.video_id}</td> --%>
                <td></td>
            </tr>


        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>

    </table>

    </div>

</body>
```

RatingServlet.java

```
package edu.csueb.cs6665.servlet;

import edu.csueb.cs6665.bean.Ratings;
import edu.csueb.cs6665.bean.User;
import edu.csueb.cs6665.util.RatingUtil;
import edu.csueb.cs6665.util.UserUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Shawn
 */
public class RatingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String dispatcher="/rating.jsp";
        String role = request.getParameter("role");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if(null != action && action.equals("delete")){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            if(id>=0){
                boolean status = RatingUtil.removeRatingByid(id);
            }
        }
        if(null != action && action.equals("update2")){
            System.out.println("INSIDE Rating update2");
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            Integer scale = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("scale"));
            Integer user_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id"));
            String timedate_rating = request.getParameter("timedate_rating");
            String text_rating = request.getParameter("text_rating");
            Integer video_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("video_id"));

            if(id>=0){
                boolean status = RatingUtil.updateRatingById(scale, user_id, timedate_rating, text_rating, video_id, id);
            }
        }
        if(null != action && action.equals("update")){
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            Integer scale = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("scale"));
            Integer userid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id"));
            String ratingdate = request.getParameter("timedate_rating");
            String text = request.getParameter("text_rating");
            Integer videoid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("video_id"));


            if(null != id){
                Ratings rating = new Ratings();
                rating.setId(id);
                rating.setScale(scale);
                rating.setUserid(userid);
                rating.setTimedate(ratingdate);
                rating.setRating(text);
                rating.setVideo(videoid);


                request.setAttribute("newrating", rating);
                dispatcher="/ratingupdate.jsp";

            }
        }
        if(null != action && action.equals("insert")){
            Integer scale = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("scale"));
            Integer userid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id"));
            String ratingdate = request.getParameter("timedate_rating");
            String text = request.getParameter("text_rating");
            Integer videoid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("video_id"));


            Ratings rating = new Ratings(scale, userid, ratingdate, text, videoid);

            //product.setReleasedate(releasedate);

            if(null != scale){
                boolean status = RatingUtil.insertRating(rating);
            }
        }
        if(action.equals("load")){
        System.out.println("Inside RatingServlet, loading");
        List<Ratings> rating = RatingUtil.getRatings();
        request.setAttribute("newratings", rating);
            if(role=="user"){
                dispatcher="/ratinglist.jsp";
            }
        }

        if(action.equals("list")){
        System.out.println("Inside RatingServlet, listing");
        List<Ratings> rating = RatingUtil.getRatings();
        request.setAttribute("newrating", rating);
        dispatcher="/ratinglist.jsp";

        }
        List<Ratings> rating = RatingUtil.getRatings();
        request.setAttribute("newrating", rating);



        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(dispatcher).forward(request, response);
    }
```

Rating.java

```
package edu.csueb.cs6665.bean;

import java.util.Date;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 */
public class Ratings implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private int scale;
    private int user_id;
    private int video_id;
    private String timedate_rating;
    private String text_rating;



     public Ratings(){

    }


        public Ratings(int scale, int user_id, String timedate_rating, String text_rating, int video_id) {
        this.setScale(scale);
        this.setUserid(user_id);
        this.setTimedate(timedate_rating);
        this.setRating(text_rating);
        this.setVideo(video_id);
    }

        public Ratings(int scale, int user_id, String timedate_rating, String text_rating, int video_id, int id) {
        this.setScale(scale);
        this.setUserid(user_id);
        this.setTimedate(timedate_rating);
        this.setRating(text_rating);
        this.setVideo(video_id);
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public int getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(int scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.user_id = id;
    }

    public int getUserid() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUserid(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getTimedate() {
        return timedate_rating;
    }

    public void setTimedate(String timedate) {
        this.timedate_rating = timedate;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return text_rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String text_rating) {
        this.text_rating = text_rating;
    }

     public int getVideo() {
        return video_id;
    }

    public void setVideo(int video_int) {
        this.video_id = video_int;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess it's because of the way in which the variables and getters/setters are named in Ratings for text_rating.  You could try to rename the getter and setter getTextRating and setTextRating and see if that does the trick.  It may not be able to get text_rating in the .jsp because there's no getter that matches that name (only getRating).